# VSCode - Integrated Terminal - PowerShell - Syntax Highlighting - PSReadLine

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, psreadline

On a Windows 7 machine, on the current version of VS Code and PowerShell 5.0.10586.117.

The integrated terminal for PowerShell has no color syntax highlighting.  Changing the PSReadLine options has not effect and revert back when restarting the terminal session or upon a re-launch of VS Code.

Is this expected behavior or a bug?  The syntax highlighting works in PowerShell.exe and PowerShell ISE.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why.  The default integrated terminal in VSCode is 32bit cmd.exe.  PSReadLine does not work on 32bit.  If you set the default integrated terminal to PowerShell 64bit color syntax highlighting via PSReadLine works.  not sure if the settings stay yet, as i haven't tested it.  Also did not test if setting terminal to 64bit cmd.exe also worked.

Comment: "PSReadLine does not work on 32bit" - correction - it "does not work" only if it is not made available to the 32-bit instance of PowerShell.